# How do I count the points in a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a script, below is just a sample...
But I have several tasks, and when a task is successful points are awarded.
At the end, I want to calculate the points IF the task is correct.

How do I do this?

```
Function Task_1
{
    
    Process 
    {
    
        Write-Output "Task has failed - Points awarded:0"

    }

}

Function Task_2
{
    
    Process 
    {
    
        Write-Output "Task has passed - Points awarded:12"

    }

}

Function Task_3
{
    
    Process 
    {
    
        Write-Output "Task has passed - Points awarded:34"

    }

}

Function Task_4
{
    
    Process 
    {
    
        Write-Output "Task has failed - Points awarded:0"

    }

}

Task_1
Task_2
Task_3
Task_4
```

There are multiple ways to do it, But I just want a simple summary of the failed tasks count, and the passed task points.

Thanks,

Comment: well it would definitely be easier if you were returning objects from your functions instead of strings. an object with 2 properties (`Status` and `Points`) would be much easier to handle than having to parse a string...

Comment: I am not a (good) programmer, so do you have an example somewhere.? As I have no clue what you are talking about...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you output objects from your function then the analytical part is much easier to handle, you could have an object like this as the result of all your tasks:

```
Task   Status          Points
----   ------          ------
Task_1 Task has failed      0
Task_2 Task has passed     12
Task_3 Task has passed     34
Task_4 Task has failed      0


TotalPointsAwared PercentagePassed TasksPassed
----------------- ---------------- -----------
               46 50%              {Task_2, Task_3}
```

The code would look like this:

```bash
Function Task_1 {
    Process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Task   = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
            Status = 'Task has failed'
            Points = 0
        }
    }
}

Function Task_2 {
    Process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Task   = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
            Status = 'Task has passed'
            Points = 12
        }
    }
}

Function Task_3 {
    Process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Task   = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
            Status = 'Task has passed'
            Points = 34
        }
    }
}

Function Task_4 {
    Process {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            Task   = $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name
            Status = 'Task has failed'
            Points = 0
        }
    }
}

$result = @(
    Task_1
    Task_2
    Task_3
    Task_4
)

$passedTests = $result.Where{ $_.Status -eq 'Task has passed' }
$percentPassed = $passedTests.Count / $result.Count

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

[pscustomobject]@{
    TotalPointsAwared = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int[]] $passedTests.Points)
    PercentagePassed  = $percentPassed.ToString('P0')
    TasksPassed       = $passedTests.Task
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thank for this, but now my `Write-Output "Task has failed - Points awarded:0"` is no longer displayed ... how do I get it back?

Comment: @I-1 the idea is to output an object instead of a string so that line can be removed and use what I showed here instead

Comment: ok I understand, but what should I do it I ALSO want to output the string? so the string AND the object?

Comment: @I-1 you could change `Write-Output` for `Write-Host` so that the string goes to the information stream.

Comment: thank worked! Awsome! thank you!

Comment: I do have one more question, your output shows an output if the finished  "passed" tasks... but the results are put side by side and it is not displaying everything with a lit of tasks output how do I get this in a list?

Comment: @I-1 I have updated my answer (_i think thats why you're looking for ?_) not sure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253973/discussion-between-i-1-and-santiago-squarzon).